# Google Places - Current places throws: An internal error occurred in the Places API library

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

> The operation couldn’t be completed. An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/support).

I'm using the Current Place api and I'm getting this error the entire day today. It worked fine until now but today it started trowing that error every time.

I thought it could be because of the limits, but I've raised the limit by enabling billing and I also saw in google developers console that I had 50 requests for the last day and 500 for the entire month. Default limit is 1000 requests per day or 150k per day if you've enabled billing. So it seems like this is not the reason.

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

Comment: Same issue since yesterday.

Comment: +1 I have the same issue. Started today. JavaScript version works perfectly fine with the same credentials.

Comment: If someone needs more sophisticated description here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165012/google-places-autocomplete-on-ios-cant-load-search-results-try-again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging on other people's comments and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44165485/4043853) answer it seems like this was a temporary issue on Google's end. Everything started working on it's own.